# Primes of the form 1..1

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

For $n \ge 1$ an integer, let's denote

$u_n = \sum_{k = 0}^{n-1} 10^k$

That is $u_1 = 1$, $u_2 = 11$, $u_3 = 111$, $u_4 = 1111$, ...

My question is the following : **Which of them are prime numbers ?**

What I know so far :

- If $u_n$ is prime, then $n$ is prime (meaning there's an obvious factorization when $n$ is not prime).
- When $p$ is prime, $u_p$ can either be prime (2, 19 and 23 being the only examples I found so far) or not prime (all primes up to 67 with the exception of 2, 19 and 23). But I haven't been able to see any pattern.

Any thought is welcome. Maybe a sub-question would be to know whether there's a finite or infinite number of such primes. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You mean k starts with 0? see this form: $(10^(n+1)-1)/9$ which is equivallent to yours, if it helps...

Comment: Note: these are called repunit primes http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repunit

Comment: @tomerg : Yes that's what I meant. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @ Douglas S. Stones : Thanks for the reference. Also I see I had forgotten $u_{19}$ somehow. So it seems it's an open problem. This question was asked to me on an exam, so I thought there might be an easy answer I had overlooked.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[OEIS](http://oeis.org/A004023) has a list of the number of 1's where these are prime.  It only has eight of them, the next is 317.  So you could have looked for a while.

Comment: Thank you. Factoring $u_{71}$ already took a considerable amount of time. I surrendered at that point.

Comment: @Joel Cohen: Primality tests are usually much faster than factoring.  A primality test on that number revealed that it is composite in less than a millisecond.

Comment: @ Charles : You're right. At first, I was also looking for a pattern in the factorization (any obvious factor). I should have had switched to just testing primality after a while.